# indexPath.row always gives zero (why not work?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Prompt, here is a code that sorts the dictionary by distance, I need to pass a variable coord to detailview where it is separated into position and put the marker on karte.No why coord gives 0 and how do I transfer it to the coordinates?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
 {[self setupArray];
 [super viewDidLoad];}

-(void)setupArray{    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [states setObject: @12 forKey:@"60.050043,30.345783"];
    [states setObject: @11 forKey:@"60.037389,30.322094"];
    [states setObject: @32 forKey:@"60.037329,30.322014"];
    [states setObject: @1 forKey:@"59.957387,30.324681"];
    NSLog(@"%f",betweenDistance);
    NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
                             {
                                 if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
                                 {
                                     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                                 }
                                 if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
                                 {
                                     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                                 }

                                 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
                             }];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedStates);
    NSMutableArray* rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* key in sortedStates)
    {
        CGFloat distance = [[states objectForKey:key] floatValue];
        [rows addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", distance]];
    }
    datasource=rows;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     Detail2ViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    NSString* coord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"virable coord %@",coord);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    2015-04-23 13:25:07.361 gfhfgh[503:7361] 8845784.000000
2015-04-23 13:25:07.363 gfhfgh[503:7361] (
    "59.957387,30.324681",
    "60.037389,30.322094",
    "60.050043,30.345783",
    "60.037329,30.322014"
)
2015-04-23 13:25:07.620 gfhfgh[503:7361] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.9.14591.0
2015-04-23 13:25:10.294 gfhfgh[503:7361] as (null) it is virable coord
2015-04-23 13:25:10.296 gfhfgh[503:7361] my viraible (null)
2015-04-23 13:25:10.296 gfhfgh[503:7361] ((null)) was false: provideAPIKey: should be called at most once
```

**UPDATE2**
I use this function, it may be because it does not work?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure the cell...

    //---------- CELL BACKGROUND IMAGE -----------------------------
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];
    imageView.image = image;
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Arrow
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to call `[self setupArray]` before `[super viewDidLoad]`. Call it before.

Try to call UITableView's method `- (void)reloadData` after loading your data on `- (void)setupArray` to tell tableView's delegate that you have loaded or updated your data and want to show it on the tableView. It should resolve your problem.

FYI: In your case, `numberOfRowsInSection:` should return `[sortedStates count]` to be sure that when you tap a cell, your app will not crash.

**Update**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Call setup array after [super viewDidLoad]
    [self setupArray];
}

-(void)setupArray {

    //Do all your setupArray stuff

    //Now update the table contents
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Use [sortedStates count] here to be sure your app will not crash later
    return [sortedStates count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Detail2ViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    NSString* coord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"virable coord %@",coord);
}
```

**Update 2**

I think I found the reason ! You have a instance variable called sortedStates, but inside `- (void)setupArray` you are declaring **a local variable with the same name**, and thats why you are not getting the values within the other methods.

Try changing

```
NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) { 
    //stuff
}];
```

with

```
//without "NSArray *"
sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) { 
    //stuff
}];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand, I need to insert a `- (void)reloadData` after the `- (void)setupArray` like this:` - (void)reloadData{...} - (void)setupArray{my code}` but what I need to insert into the method `- (void)reloadData{}` ?

Comment: No, you need to call UITableView's reloadData method after doing the setupArray stuff ... I will update my answer

Comment: i do like this [self.tableView reloadData]; but cell is empty, I found out that the reason for this line return [sortedStates count]; when I return 'return 4;' virable coord is (null)

Comment: I updated my answer again ... and please, return [sortedStates count]; if possible ... you will thanks me later ...

Comment: Yes! Works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Its because sortedStates[indexPath.row]; will result into a NSDictionary.
So code should be :

```
NSDictionary *coord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];
```

Pass this value to your detailViewController and extract the coordinate there.

Comment: unfortunately does not work, I do so: NSDictionary *coord = _sortedStates[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"as %@",coord); in - (void)tableView:

Comment: What did you get in NSLog. Please post here. Also print your sortedStates in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Please print values only in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method from there i will get the ides. If you are getting values there then it means you are not able to pass it to detailController. Let me know if this is the case will update my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but  is `NSDictionary *coord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];` in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and and output null. In order to make sure that we understand each other, I laid out my file here (QTableViewController)  [link]http://cl.ly/3T3t0D0j3P1Z?_ga=1.96268442.701167339.1426154549

Comment: I think you are wrong about this ... sortedStates is not an array of dictionaries, but an array of NSStrings containing the key. (the coordinates in this case...)

Comment: Buddy you are not passing the string to detailView at all. What you need to do is create a NSString *selectedCoord in detailViewController .h file and before [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES]; line add detail.selectedCoord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];  then only your value will be passed.